# Add range to checkbox for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to have a check box associated with a number_field that when ticked, it allows a range of acceptable values. Currently I have `<%= f.check_box :proppedvolume, {:class => "myclass", :style => "mystyle",  onchange: "$(this.form).submit();"}, 1, 0 %>`. Is there a way to change that hard-coded 1 to a range such as `0..100000`?

Answer (score 0):

Use html5 range tag,

```
range_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})
```

Comment: I'm using a number_field for the value, where I have this range in place, however I would like the checkbox that is associated with the same variable to set to 0 when its not ticked, but any value in the range when ticked. How does a range_field_tag accomplish this?